# using game center with monotouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, game-center

I am trying to add Game center support to my app using MonoTouch, I looked at the sample code... And it doesn't even compile.. It gives Internal Compile error that doesn't make sense at all:   I simply created a class, added a function and pasted their code directly into it:

```
    public bool Authenticate ()
        {
        //
        // This shows how to authenticate on both iOS 6.0 and older versions
        //
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (6, 0))
            {
            //
            // iOS 6.0 and newer
            //
            GKLocalPlayer.LocalPlayer.AuthenticateHandler = (ui, error) => {

                // If ui is null, that means the user is already authenticated,
                // for example, if the user used Game Center directly to log in

                if (ui != null)
                    current.PresentModalViewController (ui, true);
                else
                    {
                    // Check if you are authenticated:
                    var authenticated = GKLocalPlayer.LocalPlayer.Authenticated;
                    }
                Console.WriteLine ("Authentication result: {0}", err);
            };
            }
        else
            {
            // Versions prior to iOS 6.0
            GKLocalPlayer.LocalPlayer.Authenticate ((err) => {
                Console.WriteLine ("Authentication result: {0}", err);
            });
            }

        }
```

And it blows up on the call to GKLocalPlayer....

What is up?  Does anyone know of a simple example to use this?  Should be able to wrap all this into a single class to create it all...  (Which is what I plan on doing, if it hasn't already been done.)

-Traderhut Games

Comment: Exactly which error do you get from the compiler? If you get an Internal error from the compiler please file a bug report with a complete project (http://bugzilla.xamarin.com), since you should never see internal errors from the compiler.

Comment: /Src/CSharp/HexMapLibrary/MainView.cs(47,47): Error CS0584: Internal compiler error: Method not found: 'MonoTouch.GameKit.GKLocalPlayer.LoadDefaultLeaderboardCategoryID'. (CS0584) (HexMapLibrary)

Comment: /Src/CSharp/HexMapLibrary/MainView.cs(59,59): Error CS1061: Type `object' does not contain a definition for `AuthenticateHandler' and no extension method `AuthenticateHandler' of type `object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) (HexMapLibrary)

Comment: /Src/CSharp/HexMapLibrary/MainView.cs(47,47): Error CS0117: `MonoTouch.GameKit.GKLocalPlayer' does not contain a definition for `LocalPlayer' (CS0117) (HexMapLibrary)

Comment: The last error is on line 67 of my file, not sure how copy changed it to 47...

Comment: please file a bug at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com with a test case for the internal compiler error, the other errors might just be fallout from that one.